# ContextMenuItem context function is not executing

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want my context menu item to be visible only if the clicked node is a link i.e.  and href is either a magnet link or a torrent link. But item is visible for all the links  because context function is not executing, can anybody help why context function is not executing?

Here is the code:

```
exports.main = function() {
var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");

var contextCode = ' self.on("context", function (node) { '+
                  ' while(node.nodeName!="A") { node = node.parentNode;  } '+
                  ' var pat_magnet = /^magnet:/i; ' +
                  ' var pat_torrent = /.torrent$/i; ' +
                  ' if(pat_torrent.test(node.href) || pat_magnet.test(node.href)) { return true; } '+
                  ' else { return false; } '+
                  ' }); ';

var clickCode = ' self.on("click", function(node,data){ '+
                  ' while(node.nodeName!="A") { node = node.parentNode;  } '+
                  ' var pat_hash = /[0-9abcdef]{32,40}/i; ' +
                  ' var result = node.href.match(pat_hash); '+
                  ' var hash = "" '
                  ' if(result != null) { hash=result[0]; } '+
                  ' var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); '+
                  ' if(hash != "") { '+
                  '     var apiCall = "https://www.furk.net/api/dl/add?api_key=*************&info_hash="+hash; '+
                  ' } '+
                  ' else{ '+
                  '     var apiCall = "https://www.furk.net/api/dl/add?api_key=*************&url="+encodeURI(node.href); '+
                  ' } '+
                  ' xhr.open("GET",apiCall,true); '+
                  ' xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ if(xhr.readyState = 4) { if (xhr.response.status = "ok") { alert("Torrent added to Furk."); } else { alert("Torrent could not be added to Furk."); } } } '+
                  ' xhr.send(null); '+
                  ' });';
cm.Item({
   label: "Add to Furk",
   context: cm.SelectorContext("a[href]"),
   contentScript: contextCode + clickCode
});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always post self-containied examples that can be directly tried in the future.

Now back to your problem: The content script actually has a syntax error.

The following line:

```
' var pat_torrent = /.torrent$/i ' +
```

lacks a semicolon, and should be:

```
' var pat_torrent = /.torrent$/i; ' +
```

The reason automatic semicolon insertion (ASI) does not work here is: The "code" is actually a string that has no newlines in it whatsoever. If there were newlines, then ASI would have worked.
Anway, another reason not to have complex content script inline. Have a look at [`contentScriptFile`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/context-menu.html#contentScriptFile).

This error is actually logged, but the presentation sucks. In the Browser Console:

> [20:57:51.707] [object Error] (expandable)

In terminal:

> console.error: context-magnet:
>    Message: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Here is a fixed, reproducible sample:

```
var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");
var contextCode = ' self.on("context", function (node) { '+
                  ' while(node.nodeName!="A") { node = node.parentNode;  } '+
                  ' var pat_magnet = /^magnet:/i; ' +
                  ' var pat_torrent = /.torrent$/i; ' +
                  ' if(pat_torrent.test(node.href) || pat_magnet.test(node.href)) { return true; } '+
                  ' else { return false; } '+
                  ' }); ';
cm.Item({
    label: "magnet test",
    context: cm.SelectorContext("a[href]"),
    contentScript: contextCode
});
```

**Edit** `' var hash = "" '` has the same problem, and there are might be other such errors that I missed skimming this new code.
As I already said, please use `contentScriptFile` and not `contentScript` for long-ish scripts.

**Another edit**

Here is [a builder](https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/209541/latest/) using `contentScriptFile`, where I also fixed a couple of other errors, the most important of which are:

- Use [`permissions`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/cross-domain.html) so that the XHR will work.
- Correctly set up the XHR to use `responseType` and `overrideMimeType()`.
- Use `onload/onerror` instead of `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: thanx for you reply! I have edited the code and gave full code now i inserted the semicolon as you suggested but still same problem context menu item is showing at every <a> not just a link that points to .torrent or a magnet link

Comment: Another edit, having a full, working example now (well, minus the missing api key, of course ;)